# Installing Tremulous on 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 64-bit, games

I want to install a game that looks really fun, called Tremulous, but when I run the installer it says:

```
 /usr/local/bin/tremulous: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I read somewhere that it has something to do with it being 32 bit when I have 64 bit. Can anyone help?

Comment: Suggest you read the FAQ at http://tremulous.net/forum/index.php?board=4.0 and then search on linux for assistance with acquiring and installing the 64-bit client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian
```

then retry launching Tremulous.

Answer (score 0):

Tremulous has been replaces by unvanquished.
Here you can download it: http://www.unvanquished.net/download#linux

Comment: Eugenio: Tremulous has not being replaced. Unvanquished is a separate game, based in Tremulous with a new engine. There is still going development with modules. For example, check: http://acidtu.be/